# Laravel - Ability to filter database using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is my first time attempting filtering and searching the mySQL database. From my research I have found out I need an AJAX call and some PHP query that will help my achieve the filtering I want to achieve.

This is what I want the AJAX search to do:

- Have an Apply button. When I click the button I want a URL to get generated and the AJAX call to happen.
- Only reload part of the page where the data queried is contented.

So far I have managed to create this:

```
$("#filteridname").change(function() {
    $value=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{$myurl}}",
        data: {'search':$value},
        success: function(data){
          $('#data-holder').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This manages to create the URL one of the filters, but it does not take the other filters into consideration. I also did not manage to create the button. I  am guessing you would need a `where` statement in the PHP to filter the database?

Would anyone be willing to assist me in creating the AJAX call and PHP query for the filters?

In total I have three filters, and when I click a button I want an AJAX call to filter my database with the three filters and return the results without having to reload the whole webpage.

EDIT: Here is my JS AJAX query:

```
$("#apply").click(function() {
    $country=$('#filter-country').val();
    $type=$('#filter-type').val();
    $year=$('#filter-year').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{$launchsitename->site_code}}",
        data: {'country':$country, 'type':$type, 'year':$year},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#data-holder').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Now I just need to create a PHP query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use propriety called .Append() instead of .html() ,also here you are getting one element value on change , if you want to get the three of them at one button click , you can make it the same way that you got the val of the first one , and just adding it to the request and handle it back in PHP to divide and execute each one or just pass the three of them to your procedure , depends on what you have

```
  $("#filteridname").change(function() {
        $value=$(this).val();
          $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "{{$myurl}}",
            data: {'search':$value},
            success: function(response){
              $('#data-holder').append(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

[Read about .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Thanks I have added that in. Now I just need to create the PHP query to filter using the URL.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer helped to solve your issue, please make sure to accept it.